# How do I install Firefox in Windows 7 (64bit) with multiple versions with updating?

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox

Default Browser: Firefox 7
Operating System: Windows 7 (64bit)

I want to install multiple versions of Firefox (for testing purposes).

I currently have Firefox 7 installed (two different profiles - one for casual use, one for web dev).

- `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P casual -no-remote`
- `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P webdev -no-remote`

I located previous versions of Firefox here:
ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

I installed Firefox 6 with a third profile

- `"F:\Programs\Firefox 6\firefox.exe" -P FireFox6 -no-remote`

The problem is that every time I attempt to install a previous version, Firefox begins to update itself (to version 7.0.1).  Ideally, I would like the most recent version auto-update and have all of the previous versions stay on the version that I install.

How do I install Firefox in Windows 7 (64bit) with multiple versions with updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the setting in `Options`, it is saved per-profile, so disable updating in old version profiles, and keep enabled in newest version profile.

[image: Firefox update]